# Find all values of $ac-bd$ where $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers, $a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2=2017$, and $ad+bc=44$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all values of $ac-bd$ where $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers, $a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2=2017$, and $ad+bc=44$.

---

I noticed that $a^2c^2=(ac)^2$ and so on for all the terms in the polynomial.  How does that help?  Am I close to something.  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2=a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2$.